# How do you create unique assignments/workflows in Zoho Creator

Tags: zoho

I would like assistance in trying to figure out how to set up a somewhat unique set of workflows.

For example, say I have several accounts, each assigned to the respective Stage 1 account representative. Each account should then be able to be submitted/assigned to the next stage, e.g. Stage 2 account representative, Stage 3 account representative. Each representative should also be able to send the account back down.

So, something like this:

Jones Account: Stage 1 Jones Account Representative -> Stage 2 Jones Account Representative -> Stage 3 Jones Account Representative

Smith Account: Stage 1 Smith Account Representative -> Stage 2 Smith Account Representative -> Stage 3 Smith Account Representative

Brown Account: Stage 1 Brown Account Representative -> Stage 2 Brown Account Representative -> Stage 3 Brown Account Representative

Is there a way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Zoho Creator. You have to create separate form to store  all the stage 1, stage2 and stage 3 representatives for each user.

When the form submitted by the user A, you have to fetch the details from the form you have created to get a stage 1 representative of the user A and vice versa.

Check out the Expense Management application published in [Zoho Creator Marketplace](https://creator.zoho.com/platform/public/index)

https://creator.zoho.com/platform/public/showAppInfo?ownername=zohodogfood&callbackUrl=expense-management

Which has the same implementation what you are expecting.